# Wordpress - Show preview of all but current post in sidebar widget

Tags: wordpress, widget

i have 4 posts belonging to "news" category. I've added a this code in single.php to show the title of other posts in the same category in the sidebar.

```
<?php
    $query = "showposts=10&orderby=rand&cat=";      
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    $query .= $category->cat_ID .","; 
    }       
    query_posts($query);
?>
<ul class="related grid_5">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_title() ?></li>
     <?php endwhile; ?>      
</ul>
```

using this i can retrieve all posts in the same category and display them and all 4 titles belonging to "news" are displayed in the widget. but I'm on post#3 how can show only #1, #2, and #4 titles in the widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you captured the ID of your currently displayed post, you could add a conditional check to avoid displaying it in the while loop.

**1. Get ID of current post**

I'm assuming you're outside the loop as you're in your sidebar, so you could get the current post ID like so:

```
global $wp_query;
$currentPost = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

However, if you are in the loop, the following will work:

```
global $post;
$currentPost = $post->ID;
```

**2. Skip printing of current post's title**

Once you've got the current post's ID, skipping the print is pretty straightforward:

```
<ul class="related grid_5">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        if( $post->ID != $currentPost ) ?>
            <li><?php the_title() ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>      
</ul>
```